# How to display result and handle errors # 1242?

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1242

I want to:

```
if the value qty_out! = 0, then set qty_out = 0
```

Help me to display results

```
SELECT
    SUBSTR(stok_control.tgl_faktur,9,2) AS 'tanggal',
    SUBSTR(stok_control.tgl_faktur,6,2) AS 'bulan',
    CONCAT(
        (SELECT(
            IFNULL(stok_control.faktur_beli,''))
        )       
        ,
        (SELECT(
            IFNULL(stok_control.faktur_jual,''))
        )
    ) AS 'faktur',
    bahan.id AS 'kode_bahan',
    bahan.nm_bahan AS 'nama_bahan',

    stok_control.qty_in AS 'masuk',
    (
    SELECT IF(stok_control.qty_out != '',0,0) 
    FROM 
        stok_control
    WHERE 
        stok_control.faktur_beli !=''
    ) AS 'keluar'

FROM
    stok_control 
LEFT JOIN bahan ON stok_control.id_bahan=bahan.id
```

---

@eggyal, I have changed your code to be:

```
SELECT 
    SUBSTR(sc.tgl_faktur, 9, 2) AS 'tanggal',
    SUBSTR(sc.tgl_faktur, 6, 2) AS 'bulan',
    CONCAT(
        IFNULL(sc.faktur_beli, ''),
        IFNULL(sc.faktur_jual, '')
        ) AS 'faktur',
    b.id        AS 'kode_bahan',
    b.nm_bahan  AS 'nama_bahan',
    (SELECT IFNULL(sc.qty_in,0))  AS 'masuk',
    (SELECT
        (
            IF(faktur_beli <> '',
                0,
                (SELECT sc.qty_out)
            ) 
        )

    ) AS 'qty_out'
FROM   
    stok_control sc LEFT JOIN bahan b ON sc.id_bahan = b.id
```

I've tried to reference an existing but still error...

Comment: This error occurs for statements where the subquery must return at most one row but returns multiple rows. Check here http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/subquery-errors.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want to:
>
> ```
> if the value qty_out! = 0, then set qty_out = 0
> ```

Do you mean that you want `qty_out` to be 0 irrespective of its original value?

```
SELECT SUBSTR(sc.tgl_faktur, 9, 2) AS tanggal,
       SUBSTR(sc.tgl_faktur, 6, 2) AS bulan,
       CONCAT(
         IFNULL(sc.faktur_beli, ''),
         IFNULL(sc.faktur_jual, '')
       )                           AS faktur,
       b.id                        AS kode_bahan,
       b.nm_bahan                  AS nama_bahan,
       sc.qty_in                   AS masuk,
       0                           AS qty_out
FROM   stok_control sc LEFT JOIN bahan b ON sc.id_bahan = b.id
```

Comment: yes, for example, initial value is greater than 0, then it should be changed to 0, if the initial value 0, then let it remain

Comment: @user1764869: So then just select constant `0`, as above.

Comment: I changed your code :SELECT 
 SUBSTR(sc.tgl_faktur, 9, 2) AS 'tanggal',
 SUBSTR(sc.tgl_faktur, 6, 2) AS 'bulan',
 CONCAT(
  IFNULL(sc.faktur_beli, ''),
  IFNULL(sc.faktur_jual, '')
  ) AS 'faktur',
 b.id  AS 'kode_bahan',
 b.nm_bahan  AS 'nama_bahan',
 (SELECT IFNULL(sc.qty_in,0))  AS 'masuk',
 (SELECT
  (
   IF(faktur_beli <> '',
    0,
    (SELECT sc.qty_out)
   ) 
  )

 ) AS 'qty_out'
FROM   
 stok_control sc LEFT JOIN bahan b ON sc.id_bahan = b.id